# Nativescript 5 - Cannot profile with xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I'm using {N}5.1.0, and I'm trying to debug some memory leaks that I have in the application.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/hunting-memory-leaks-with-android-studio-and-xcode). The problem is that when I press on 'profile', the *instrument* pane opens, the application is deployed to the device (a simulator) but it's not started. And if I click on the icon of the app on the simulator to manually start it, it shows the splashscreen and then silently stops.

I'm using xcode 10.1

I've already tried to wipe out all simulator data, restart simulator and xcode with no results.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go to Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme then select *Profile* and switch *Build Configuration* to *Debug*